# Solve PostgreSQL table bloat without affecting reads/writes?

Tags: postgresql

I have a large postgresql table that I think has started to become bloated, and I'd like to fix that. Normally I could do a `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER`, but I'm wondering if I can fix the bloat without affecting read/write performance.

If there's index bloat, I can (manually) create a new index concurrently that indexes the same things as the old one, but with a different name, and when it's created, I can delete the old, bloated, one. This allows me to fix the index bloat with minimal affect on production use (since there is always an index there, and reads & writes aren't blocked).

Is there any approach like that that would work for tables? I could `CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE old_bloated_table INCLUDING ...`, which would create the table afresh. Then a drop & rename. But the data could be out of sync. Is there anyway to ensure the data would be the same between tables? (In the case of the index, the index will always be in sync with the table).

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack